# Is it good practice to standardize your data in a regression with panel/longitudinal data?

Tags: r, regression, standardization

In general, I standardize my independent variables in regressions, in order to properly compare the coefficients (this way they have the same units: standard deviations). However, with panel/longitudinal data, I'm not sure how I should standardize my data, especially if I estimate a hierarchical model.

To see why it can be a potential problem, assume you have $i = 1, \ldots, n$ individuals measured along $t=1,\ldots, T$ periods and you measured a dependent variable, $y_{i,t}$ and one independent variable $x_{i,t}$. If you run a complete pooling regression, then it's ok to standardize your data in this way: $x.z = (x- \text{mean}(x))/\text{sd}(x)$, since it will not change t-statistic. On the other hand, if you fit an unpooled regression, i.e., one regression for each individual, then you should standardize your data by individual only, not the whole dataset (in R code):

```
for (i in 1:n) {
  for ( t in 1:T) x.z[i] =  (x[i,t] - mean(x[i,]))/sd(x[i,]) 
}
```

However, if you fit a simple hierarchical model with a varying intercept by individuals, then you are using a shrinkage estimator, i.e, you are estimating a model between pooled and unpooled regression. How should I standardize my data? Using the whole data like a pooled regression? Using only individuals, like in the unpooled case?

Answer (score 11):

I can't see that standardization is a good idea in ordinary regression or with a longitudinal model.  It makes predictions harder to obtain and doesn't solve a problem that needs solving, usually.  And what if you have $x$ and $x^2$ in the model.  How do you standardize $x^2$?  What if you have a continuous variable and a binary variable in the model?  How do you standardize the binary variable?  Certainly not by its standard deviation, which would cause low prevalence variables to have greater importance.

In general it's best to interpret model effects on the original scale of $x$.

Comment: @Frank Harrell - good points about the problems associated with the conditions you outline but if one has all continuous variables with different scales then isn't standardization the only way to compare slopes?

Comment: @Frank, I suppose it depends on what type of models you are running, but standardization of predictor variables is often useful.  Centering them means that the intercept becomes interpretable as the mean predicted outcome and the relative importance of different predictors becomes more obvious.  I usually leave binary predictors alone, but sometimes other scaling options are worth considering.  Finally, in some cases having predictors with wildly different standard deviations can lead to computational/convergence problems.

Comment: I'm not clear on how such standardization adds clarity rather than subtracts from it.  Also, the mean is not the obvious choice for centering (median? mode? 43rd percentile? choice of dispersion measure is even more problematic)  Relative importance can be judged in many ways, e.g., partial $R^2$, partial $\chi^2$, inter-quartile-range covariate effects, ...  Also I have not found standardization to be helpful computationally when using modern matrix math routines such as the ones R uses under the hood.  Kenny note that standardization is not the way to compare slopes.

Comment: If you have binary variables, don't standardize them, only continuous one. See this article by Gelman (<http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/standardizing7.pdf>, suggesting dividing variables by two standard deviations. In any case, it helps to achive convergence if you are fitting a Bayesian model.

Comment: And I don't see why it would be better to interpret effects on the original scale. The effect of GDP on a logistic regresssion is hard to interpret looking only to coefficients, because GDP is much bigger than probability scale. Interactions are better understood with standardized coefficients or centered variables. Finally, if you have $x$ and $x^{2}$, in this case don't standardize.

Comment: There are too many exceptions then for standardization to be a recommended procedure in general.  And standardization does not make interpretation of odds ratios easier.  In fact the reverse is true.  Instead, by computing an inter-quartile-range odds ratio (as done automatically in the R rms package) you can say that the effect of moving GDP from a to b absolute units is to increase odds of Y=1 by x.  And there are too many choices of standardization (IQR, Gini's mean difference, SD, inter-decile range, etc.) to make interpretation of interactions straightforward.

Comment: One further comment.  It is almost an accident that a relationship is linear.  This only happens in general in Newtonian mechanics or when relating one variable to the same variable measured at a different time.  Nature is nonlinear the vast majority of the time.  With sufficient sample sizes, the nonlinearity (e.g., significance of nonlinear spline basis functions) becomes apparent.

Comment: I never interpret logitic regression coefficients in odds-ratio, I find them confusing! In any case, interactions without standardization is pretty annoing to interpret in logistic regressions. My regresssions always have interactions terms, sometimes more than one.

Comment: @Frank Harrel, thanks for your anwer. I voted it up, because it's a good answer, with a valid point of view, which enhanced my knowledge of the subject. However, I still desagree with you about standardization, even though it is not always the case the best solution to help interpreting coefficients. And because I desagree with you and I think my question was not properly answered, I'll not mark your answer as an accepted answer.

Comment: I maintain that such standardization (which is arbitrary - why not standardize by the inter-quintile range?) makes interpretation worse.  Staying close to the original scale usually helps because that's the scale of the experiment.  It is absolutely necessary to understand odds ratios to understand logistic regression.

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative to standardization to bring variables measured with different scales to the same metric. It's called Proportion of Maximum Scaling (POMS), and it dies not mess with the multivariate distributions as z-transformation tends to do.

Todd Little explicitly recommends POMS over z-standardization in his book on longitudinal structural equation modeling. Z-transformation comes with additional problems when dealing with longitudinal data, see here: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4569815/